# Why does "new Date().toString()" work given Javascript operator precedence?

Tags: javascript, parsing, operator-precedence

[MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) that there are two operators in Javscript that share the highest precedence:

- The left-associative member operator: `foo.bar`
- The right-associative new operator: `new Foo()`

I usually explicitly separate the two: `(new Date()).toString()`
But I frequently see both of them combined: `new Date().toString()`

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117457/disambiguation-of-expressions-with-neighboring-operators-of-different-associativ), the reason the second way works is that it's the second operator's associativity that matters when both operators have equal precedence. In this case, the member operator is left associative which means `new Date()` is evaluated first.

However, if that's the case, then why does `new Date.toString()` fail? After all, `new Date` is [just syntactic sugar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034941/new-myobject-vs-new-myobject) for `new Date()`. The above argument says it should work, but it obviously doesn't.

What am I missing?

Comment: Because the syntactic sugar doesn't extend to instantiation AND member access.  It depends on the compiler.  Somewhat similar scenario: VB.NET has `Dim x As New ...` but I don't believe we can do `Dim x As New Date().ToString()`.  We can do `Dim x As String = new Date().ToString()`.

Comment: The `()` operator will execute the constructor before the `.` accesses it's properties.

Comment: @ps2goat You're right, but based on the answer below this is due to the specified grammar rather than compiler whimsy.

Comment: The syntax-rules for 'new' are complicated  which can easily lead to errors.  My preferred solution to that is to  make 'new' a static method, which internally calls 'new this (...)'.  Then the syntax for creating new instances looks just like any other method- call and I don't have to think twice about it.  For instance I could write:   MyDate..new().toString()  .

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [syntax](http://es5.github.io/#A.3) is

```
MemberExpression :
    PrimaryExpression
    FunctionExpression
    MemberExpression [ Expression ]
    MemberExpression . IdentifierName
    new MemberExpression Arguments
```

`new foo().bar` cannot be parsed as `new (foo().bar)` because `foo().bar` is not a MemberExpression. Moreover, `new foo()` cannot be parsed as `new (foo())`, for the same reason. Conversely, `new foo.bar` *is* parsed as `new (foo.bar)` because `foo.bar` is a valid MemberExpression (an interpretation `(new foo).bar` is impossible because the grammar is greedy).

That is, the precedence rule is: dot beats new, new beats call (parens).

```
.  -> new -> ()
```

Furthermore, looking directly at the grammar demystifies the syntactic sugar that turns `new Foo` into `new Foo()`. It's simply NewExpression ← new NewExpression ← new PrimaryExpression:

```
NewExpression :
    MemberExpression
    new NewExpression
```

Comment: Isn't `foo()` a FunctionExpression, making `foo().bar` a MemberExpression by this definition?

Answer (score 8):

I'm the guy who wrote both the question and the answer of "[Disambiguation of expressions with neighboring operators of different associativity and same precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15117457/783743)", and when I wrote that I didn't have JavaScript in my mind.

The language I was considering was Haskell, which is a functional programming language. Operators in such languages are simply functions and are much easier to reason about. However I wrote my answer in a manner which didn't assume any programming language.

On the other hand JavaScript is a traditional programming language and expressions in JavaScript are disambiguated based on elaborate parsing rules which are very different from the parsing rules employed by Haskell.

In particular JavaScript parsing rules seem to be greedy. For example take your first example:

```
new Date().toString()
```

Here the function call after `Date` shields `Date` from the member operator. Hence `new`, being greedy, can still only operate on `Date` instead of `Date().toString`. Hence we have:

```
((new Date()).toString)()
```

In the second example we have:

```
new Date.toString()
```

Here there's no function call after `Date` to shield it from the member operator. Hence `new`, being greedy, operates on the expression `Date.toString`. Hence we have:

```
(new (Date.toString))()
```

@thg435's answer backs up this claim. The point is that I was discussing a formal system which is totally different from the one implemented by JavaScript parsers. The formal system I was discussing treats operators and operands both as first class values.