# Unable to run simple example using library https://github.com/hiddentao/linear-algebra

Tags: javascript, linear-algebra

I'm attempting to use library : https://github.com/hiddentao/linear-algebra

Doc states to use :

```
Include dist/linear-algebra.js script into your HTML.

In the browser the library is exposed via the linearAlgebra() function.
```

But using code :

```
<script src="linear-algebra.js"></script>

<!-- https://github.com/hiddentao/linear-algebra
 -->

<script>

var m = new linearAlgebra().Matrix([ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]);
console.log( m.rows );     // 2
console.log( m.cols );     // 3
console.log( m.data );     // [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ]

</script>
```

Causes Chrome error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of undefined
```

I'm not using the library in the correct way , should be just able to use `linearAlgebra()` ref ?

Any other recommendations js math libraries appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new linearAlgebra().Matrix(...)
```

is interpreted as

```
( new linearAlgebra() ).Matrix(...)
```

due to JS precedence rules (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17587899/989121) for details).

Enclose it in parentheses to get what you want:

```
new ( linearAlgebra().Matrix )(...)
```

Comment: `new (linearAlgebra()).Matrix` would work as well. Or you can follow the documentation for your library and import the symbols distinctly, such as

`var linAlg = linearAlgebra(), Vector = linAlg.Vector, Matrix = linAlg.Matrix;`


See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0z8eu2y2/) for some examples.