# Starting a thread in Java and operator precedence

Tags: java, multithreading

In one of our Java projects I found the following code for starting a thread:

```
new WorkerThread(socket).start();
```

Now according to [operator precedence](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/) in Java **this is wrong**! It should be instead:

```
(new WorkerThread(socket)).start();
```

Now my question:

Why is it still working? Are there any dangers?

Just for reference, *WorkerThread* is implemented pretty straightforward:

```
private class WorkerThread extends Thread
{
    private Socket socket;

    public WorkerThread(Socket socket)
    {
        super();
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            /* do stuff... */
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should be that call wrong according to operator precedence? You create a new object and then you call the start method...

Comment: where did you hear that this is wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, it is perfectly valid, according the the Java syntax.

Comment: Am I the only one here who heard about "lexical analysis" in his studies?

Comment: @chrset nope, but the documentation that you did link in Mena´s answer allows a lot of confusion, especially since you seem to only verify what is written in the third column(`Level`) but do not take note of what is written in the last colum (`Associativity`). All in all, if you invoke a constructor, the `.` followed afterwards doesn´t have a higher precedence. The constructor will return an instance of the object and the follow up method will be invoked on this instance.

Comment: I found this post that describes it very well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17587899/1823476. I know it's about JavaScript but I guess the Java grammar is pretty similar in that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the website you link to is wrong, or at least incomplete. First of all, the Java Language Specification doesn't explicitly define operator precedence. The operator precedence is defined implicitly by the grammar. The "`.`" operator (although the JLS doesn't call it an operator) also has no single precedence.

For example, the following code is legal and does what you would expect:

```
class A {
    static class B {
        void f() {
            System.out.println("f()");
        }
    }
}

public class Foo {    
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new A.B().f();
    }
}
```

The `new`-expression is paranthesized as follows: `(new A.B()).f();`. So apparently the dot has both higher and lower precedence than `new`. The trick is that the dot appears in different rules. In the example, the first dot is generated by the rule `ClassOrInterfaceTypeToInstantiate` in [JLS section 15.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9), while the second dot is generated by the rule `MethodInvocation` in [JLS section 15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-MethodInvocation).

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any "dangers".

The `start` method is invoked on the previous object in the chain, which appears to be extending `Thread`.

This is not about operator precedence but proper parenthesis, which in this case are perfectly fine as is.

You may find other situations where parenthesis are relevant, e.g. when casting and invoking a method to the cast object inline.

Here's a couter-example of parenthesis order relevance when casting:

```
class A {
    void a(){}
}
class B extends A {
    void b(){}
}

A a = new B();
(B)a.b(); // won't compile
((B)a).b(); // fine
```

Comment: @chrset no. It's an instance of `WorkerThread` because you are invoking `new WorkerThread(socket)`, which is an invocation to its constructor thus returning an instance.

Comment: No because . has a higher precedence as "new". Therefore it first evaluates *WorkerThread(socket).start()* and then *new*

Comment: @chrset who told you that?

Comment: Look here: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/.
Operator . for accessing object members has the highst precedence

Comment: @chrset nope. The invocation is again on the constructor, not on the class. And the article you reference seems to be relevant for mathematical expressions only.

Comment: @Mena it seems that the table wants to cover up every keyword. But the third column seems to be more important then the first column where the precedence order is defined. Guess that´s somehow where the missinterpretation of precedence came from

Comment: @KevinEsche you have a sharp eye. Anyway, the linked documentation seems to be mixing up a lot, which as you say, allows some degree of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Operator precedence is not something to ponder over here, as the only operator is the `new` operator.

So, it creates a new object, and then calls the method `start()`.